# owl:TransitiveProperty in query

Tags: sparql, owl, semantic-web

I have done a family tree. I also defined transitive property: childOf. Now I want to make SPARQL Query which give me all descendants of one of members of family. How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your triple store supports OWL reasoning and you've defined your `childOf` property to be transitive (shouldn't it be called `descendantOf` by the way!), then it should infer `childOf` properties directly between all related nodes.  So, it should be enough to query it like this (prefixes omitted for brevity):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * {
  ?x :childOf ?y
}
```

However, if your triple store doesn't do OWL reasoning, you can achieve the same result by using SPARQL 1.1 property paths to query for indirect relationships:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * {
  ?x :childOf+ ?y
}
```

Note the '+' after the `childOf`, this means that the predicate may be matched 1 or more times.  More details about SPARQL 1.1 property paths are at http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/.