# Speeding up SPARQL query on GraphDB

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, graphdb

I'm trying to speed up and to optimize this query

```
select distinct ?root where { 
    ?root a :Root ;
          :hasnode* ?node ;
          :hasnode* ?node2 .

    ?node a :Node ;
           :hasAnnotation ?ann .
    ?ann :hasReference ?ref .
    ?ref a :ReferenceType1 .

    ?node2 a :Node ;
            :hasAnnotation ?ann2 .
    ?ann2 :hasReference ?ref2 .
    ?ref2 a :ReferenceType2 .

}
```

Basically, I'm analyzing some trees and I want to get all trees (i.e., trees' roots) which do have at least a couple of underlying nodes with a pattern like this one:

```
?node_x a :Node ;
       :hasAnnotation ?ann_x .
?ann_x :hasReference ?ref_x .
?ref_x a :ReferenceTypex .
```

one with `x = 1` and the other with `x = 2`.

Since in my graph one node may have at most one `:hasAnnotation` predicate, I do not have to specify that those nodes must be different.

**The problem**

The aforementioned query describes what I need but does have a very bad performance. After minutes and minutes of execution, it is still running.

**My (ugly) solution: breaking it in half**

I noticed that if a look for a node pattern at a time, I get my result in some seconds(!).

Sadly enough, my current approach consists in running the following query type twice:

```
select distinct ?root where { 
    ?root a :Root ;
          :hasnode* ?node .

    ?node a :Node ;
           :hasAnnotation ?ann_x .
    ?ann_x :hasReference ?ref_x .
    ?ref_x a :ReferenceTypex .
}
```

one with `x = 1` and the other with `x = 2`.

Saving partial results (i.e., `?root`s) in 2 sets, let's say `R1` and `R2` and finally calculating intersection between those resultsets.

Is there a way to speed up my initial approach to get results just by leveraging SPARQL?

PS: I'm working with GraphDB.

Comment: Auto-hint: a nested query could help

Comment: Try to enclose both groups into `{}`. PS. Does FactForge contain some data similar to yours?

Comment: About the PS: Unfortunately no or, at least, I'm not aware of any similarity.

Comment: Anyway, they are a kind of annotated genealogy trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the specific dataset I can give you only some general directions how to optimize the query:

**Avoid using DISTINCT for large datasets**

The GraphDB query optimiser will not rewrite automatically the query to use EXISTS for all patterns not participating in the projection. The query semantics is to find that there is at least one such pattern, but not give me all bindings and then eliminate the duplicated results.

**Materialize the property paths**

GraphDB has a very efficient forward chaining reasoner and relatively not so optimised property path expansion. If you are not concerned for the write/data update performance, I suggest you to declare `:hasNode` as a transitive property (see [owl:TransitiveProperty in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645778/owltransitiveproperty-in-query)), which will eliminate the property path wildcard. This will boost many times the query speed.

Your final query should look like:

```
select ?root where { 
    ?root a :Root ;
          :hasnode ?node ;
          :hasnode ?node2 .

    FILTER (?node != ?node2)

    FILTER EXISTS {
        ?node a :Node ;
               :hasAnnotation ?ann .
        ?ann :hasReference ?ref .
        ?ref a :ReferenceType1 .
    }

    FILTER EXISTS {
        ?node2 a :Node ;
                :hasAnnotation ?ann2 .
        ?ann2 :hasReference ?ref2 .
        ?ref2 a :ReferenceType2 .
    }
}
```

Comment: `:hasnode a owl:TransitiveProperty` flattens my trees structure at every node level and avoids property paths. It works also with OWL Horst optimized. Great! But what if I want one entry per matching tree's root but I have to avoid using `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Another question: why did you use `FILTER EXISTS` instead of just writing those triples as a unique main pattern?

Comment: Note: without `FILTER EXISTS` the query seems faster

Answer (score 2):

Well, putting together auto-hint :) and Stanislav's suggestion I came up with a solution.

**Solution 1 nested query**

Nesting the query in the following way, I get the result in `15s`.

```
select distinct ?root where { 
    ?root a :Root ;
          :hasnode* ?node .
    ?node a :Node ;
          :hasAnnotation ?ann .
    ?ann :hasReference ?ref .
    ?ref a :ReferenceType1 .
    {
        select distinct ?root where { 
            ?root a :Root ;
                  :hasnode* ?node2 .
            ?node2 a :Node ;
                   :hasAnnotation ?ann2 .
            ?ann2 :hasReference ?ref2 .
            ?ref2 a :ReferenceType2 .
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:  groups into `{}`**

Grouping parts into `{}`, as suggested by Stanislav's, took `60s`.

```
select distinct ?root where { 
    {
    ?root a :Root ;
          :hasnode* ?node .

    ?node a :Node ;
           :hasAnnotation ?ann .
    ?ann :hasReference ?ref .
    ?ref a :ReferenceType1 .
    }
    {
        ?root a :Root ;
          :hasnode* ?node2 .

              ?node2 a :Node ;
            :hasAnnotation ?ann2 .
    ?ann2 :hasReference ?ref2 .
    ?ref2 a :ReferenceType2 .
    }
}
```

Probably GraphDB's optimizer builds a query plan more effective for my data in the first case (explanations are welcome).

I've ever thought about SPARQL in a 'declarative' way, but it seems like there is a massive variability in performance respect to the way you write your SPARQL. Coming from SQL, it seems to me that such a performance variability is much greater than what it happens in the relational world.

However, reading [this post](https://www.stardog.com/blog/7-steps-to-fast-sparql-queries/), it seems I'm not sufficiently aware of SPARQL optimizer dynamics. :)

Comment: FYI: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/explain-plan.html